# PageSpeed Insights Cached Results?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

We have used PSI before to measure the impact of our changes as we go through optimizing sites.  It seems it doesn't run every time anymore now though as subsequent runs load the same results as before in a few seconds.  I'm not finding any info about this in the docs.

Any one know more about this and/or how to force a new analysis?

Thanks!

Comment: PSI does not cache, are you talking about PSI or are you using Lighthouse in the browser? If it is PSI then the results are always a fresh analysis for the lab data.

Comment: I mean PSI at https://pagespeed.web.dev/.  I've never noticed it cache either until recently.  An example:

One test issues was an issue wasn't being served as .webp, https://www.screencast.com/t/DKGAsPG0rjOr.  The problem here was the image wasn't in the media library so Smush Pro's Local WebP feature hadn't converted it.  We then ran the Directory Smush which converted it, https://www.screencast.com/t/wixl5EFrcBYP. 

Running the test again though loads in 2 seconds and still shows the image as not being .webp.  Seems it's not actually testing again but just showing the old results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its browser caching related with the new UI. I just closed the window, opened PSI again and ran. It then actually ran the test again and the .webp issue now longer shows. Doing a hard-refresh on the results page also caused it to run again. Just something to watch out for I guess. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I noticed a similar behaviour since the recent update.

Just figured out that Ctr+F5 or Shift+F5 allows to refresh the score.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the new PSI UI and has since been fixed. Sorry!